# How do I fix the gap in the multiple div which is generated in while loop?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: bug in my page that it show gap but instead of the gap i have div which is in while loop]

```
`echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
 echo '<div class="product-image-wrapper">';                
 echo'<div class="single-products">';
 echo'<div class="productinfo text-center">';
 echo'<a href="product-detail.php      id='.$row[9].'&item='.$_REQUEST['item'].'&product='.$row[2].'&pro=2">';
 echo '<img  src="image/thumb_images/'.$row['6'].'" />';  // image
 $thumb='image/thumb_images/'.$row[6];
 echo '<h6>Rs. ' .ROUND($row['SellingPrice']).'/-';
 if($row['discount']>0){;
 echo ' &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>MRP. ' .$row[4].' /-</span>';
 }else{}
 echo '</h6>';
 echo'<h6>'.$row[2].'</h6>';
 $name=$row[2];`
 echo' </div>';
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';
```

CSS

```
.single-products {
 position: relative;
 }
.new, .sale {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 }

.productinfo h6{
 color:#fff;
}
.productinfo h5{
 font-size: 70%;
 text-decoration: line-through;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#999;
 }
.product-overlay h2{
 margin-top:250px;
 color: red;
 }
.single-products h6{
 color:#fff;
 font-size: 90%;
vertical-align: top;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 1;
}
.single-products span{
 font-size:12px;
 text-decoration: line-through;
 font-weight:300;
 color:#Fff;
 }
.productinfo p{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #696763;
 }
```

here i have write my bootstrap code and below i have attach my screenshot when i fixed size then it work fine but i want to fill up this gap by image... i have attach css also please read out the above code and give me answer related to problem..
please suggest me

Comment: plz provide relevant HTML, CSS code

Comment: I guess you have 4  columns with col-sm-4 in one row and hence the gap.

Comment: Better to add the HTML generated by the while loop in the question.

Comment: no i have 3 columns and each columns has 3 div and it added 3-4 columns correctly and after that it show gaping or can say null instead of image

Comment: Where are you closing the A tag? I can't seem to find a </a>

Comment: i have close </a> after last div in my code...

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Can you view the source and add the HTML generated to the post?

Comment: But you should close the A tag within it's container? As far as I can see you are closing multiple containers (where the A tag is in) before you close the A tag?

Comment: hello how do i send you my whole code?

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Not the whole code just the html generated for the above image. You can change the real data info from it and replace it with `lorem ipsum`. If not inspect the element and add the screenshot so that we can understand how the html has been generated.

Comment: [MY URL](http://fashionneck.com/necklaceset.php) open this url in firefox you may notice the error.... @ anpsmn & @ Epodax

Comment: Close the A tag inside of your container and see if that doesn't solve it, both google chrome and Firefox does this when the website is rendered, I can't say for sure this is causing it, but it just might.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Ok to reduce the gap you need to have all columns with equal heights. Solution is to have all images of equal heights, what you have is few of them have 247px as height and few have 248px.

Comment: Thank's for your answer.. i applied this and it's works fine but when i used it as responsive then image get stretch, so will u give me any specific solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to Akhil try the following solution Kuldeep. Hope it works.

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $product_count++ ;
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4" style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">';

        //put your code here
        //put your code here
        //put your code here

        echo'</div>';
        if($product_count % 3 == 0){
            echo'<div style="clear: both;"></div>'; 
        }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

kuldeep, either fix the height of the box and if there is more text you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for showing more text is there. And one other option is You need to put a `clear:both` tag after each 3 boxes. You can make it in condition loop I think.